# Class 'COM' not found

Tags: php, unix

I am trying to use COM object in my script and running the script on linux server and got below error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

You can serve a COM object to a Windows client, connect to one running on a Windows host etc, - but you [can't run it under Linux](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php).

On a Windws host running PHP >= v5 you need to enable it in php.ini:

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```